# Why is this VBA function slow?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large Excel file with a lot of manually-entered data as well as a lot of calculated columns. One set of columns holds rack numbers, which are formatted as text and are three-digit numbers. A cell may contain zero or more rack numbers. When multiple rack numbers exist in a cell, they are delimited by `/`. Because I often fat-finger the rack numbers and enter four-digit numbers by mistake, I set up a conditional formatting rule to color cells with bad rack numbers red.

Here's my rule:

```
=HAS_BAD_RACK_NO(L1834)
```

which is applied to the range `=$L$1834:$S$1981`. The exact range changes from day to day, but it's always approximately the same size. Here's the VBA function that drives it:

```
Public Function HAS_BAD_RACK_NO(ref As Range) As Boolean
    Dim re As New RegExp
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    re.Pattern = "[0-9]{4,}"
    For Each cell In ref.Cells
        If re.Test(cell.value) Then
            HAS_BAD_RACK_NO = True
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not found Then
        HAS_BAD_RACK_NO = False
    End If
End Function
```

The problem is that this conditional formatting rule greatly slows Excel down whenever I enter data in one of the cells it covers. I estimate that it takes between 1 and 10 seconds after I leave the cell for Excel to start responding again and accept keyboard input. I can't figure out why it's so slow, because it's never examining more than one cell. There's only a single-cell range.

Admittedly, this is a complex spreadsheet with several custom functions and quite a lot of conditional formatting rules, together with a large number of charts. However, through testing I've established that this slowdown only occurs when I edit a cell in the range of this particular conditional formatting rule. If I edit the range to exclude a cell I'm editing, the performance problems disappear.

This function is really simple; why is it so slow?

Comment: It's slow because it is covering all the cells in the range every time.  If you want it to highlight when you have made a typo then why not get it just to check the specific cell? Use `Worksheet_Change` and just check the `Target`

Comment: The range is always of size 1. Note how the function is called. Also, the problem with `worksheet_change` is that it breaks undo.

Comment: "conditional formatting slow" (disable updating while running your macro) -> see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions#create-faster-vba-macros

Comment: [Read/Write Large Blocks of Cells in a Single Operation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/)

Comment: @Scott just to clarify your point _The range is always of size 1_ while each instance of `HAS_BAD_RACK_NO` is called with 1 cell, you have applied the formula to 1184 cells (in your example range), whose Conditional Format all get updated on each change.  That's 1184 RegEx objects that get created each time you edit.  That's why Tim's Static approach speeds thing up so much

Answer (score 3):

In my testing this function will execute about 30x faster - uses a static regexp instead of creating a new one each time it runs:

```
Public Function HAS_BAD_RACK_NO(ref As Range) As Boolean

    Static re As RegExp    '<< use a static object

    'only create if needed
    If re is nothing then
        Set re = New RegExp
        re.Pattern = "[0-9]{4,}"
    end if

    if ref.countlarge > 1 then
        HAS_BAD_RACK_NO = True 'don't allow multiple-cell inputs
    else
        HAS_BAD_RACK_NO = re.Test(ref.value)
    end if
End Function
```

Testing sub:

```
Sub Driver()
    Dim t
    t = Timer
    'L34:S181 contains the data which the UDF processes
    With ActiveSheet.Range("L34:S181")
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

~1.3 sec for the original version, vs ~0.04 sec for the one using a static regexp.